# Mysql Query Select all data one hour before end time?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all data one hour before end time

I have my query :

```
SELECT a.end_time,u.email FROM watchlists as w 
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id =w.user_id 
LEFT JOIN auctions as a ON a.id = w.auction_id where 
a.end_time > DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Buy I have wrong display.

It shows all the data that interval of one hour for example the 
current date is `2012-05-18 12:40:20`

the data displayed are:

```
2012-05-18 12:08:20
2012-05-18 12:51:20
2012-05-18 12:41:20
```

I want to display data that one hour before end time for example:
the current time is `2012-05-18 12:40:20`

the is  `2012-05-18 13:40:20`

the past date will not be included.

How to do this in mysql query ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Should the query not be `a.end_time between curdate() and DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)` ?

Comment: +1 Shouldn't that go in the "Answers" section? Looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the query to read like

```
SELECT a.end_time,u.email FROM watchlists as w 
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id =w.user_id 
LEFT JOIN auctions as a ON a.id = w.auction_id where 
a.end_time between curdate() and DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```